# what is /dev/windrvr6

Tags: linux, unix

What is /dev/windrvr6  Is this a generic driver?  I have 2 card made by different vendors using /dev/windrvr6 and they seem to work fine.  Will this be a problem in the future?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that they both used tools from [Jungo](http://www.jungo.com/); they have products to help people make PCI drivers, and part of their common infrastructure is [WinDriver](http://www.jungo.com/st/windriver_usb_pci_driver_development_software.html).  (Despite its name, [it's also for Linux](http://www.jungo.com/st/linux.html))

I don't expect that this should be a problem.